# Is there a way to not keep creating new events to spawn in my new object each time?

Tags: unity, c#

I have an event manager to help to communicate between two scripts. One is for the script of the object itself to pass on the message to the other one which is the spawn manager(you see below). What I'm doing is working but as I create more "bosses", I will have to create more event action which I fear would be messy in the future. Is there any tips to counter this? Like for example, I just want to use one event action and that event action will help to tell my spawn script to "hey, this event is called again. time for this NEW boss to go second phase" or "this boss died, time to enter new boss" whenever this ONE event is called. Sorry for my misunderstanding of my English. Btw below is the script which I will name it accordingly to lessen the confusion.

--Spawn Script--

```
 public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("First Enemy")]
    [SerializeField] GameObject _FirstFall;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _FirstFelll_secondPhase;
  

    [Header("Second Enemy")]
    [SerializeField] GameObject _SecondFallRight;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _SecondFallLeft;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _SecondFallLeft_Phrase;
    float SpawnBetween_SecondLeft = 1.5f;
    float _nextSpawnTime_SecondLeft;

    [Header("Spawning Shards")]
    [SerializeField] GameObject _shards;
    float SpawnBetween_shard = 1.5f;
    float _nextSpawnTime_shard;

    [Header("System")]
    Vector2 cameraScreenWrap;

    public ObjectSettings[] _spawnSettings;
    bool enteringNewBoss;
    bool SecondPhase;
    bool SecondPhaseTwo;


    void Awake()
    {
        _spawnSettings[0].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
        _spawnSettings[1].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
        _spawnSettings[2].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
        _spawnSettings[3].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
        _spawnSettings[4].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
        _spawnSettings[5].NextSpawnTime = 0f;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        cameraScreenWrap = new Vector2 (Camera.main.aspect * Camera.main.orthographicSize, Camera.main.orthographicSize);

        EventManager.FirstGone += FirstEnd;
        EventManager.GoingToPhase += TriggeringPhase;
        EventManager.GoingToPhaseTwo += TriggeringPhaseTwo;

        _FirstFall.SetActive(true);
        _FirstFelll_secondPhase.SetActive(true);

        _SecondFallLeft.SetActive(true);
        _SecondFallRight.SetActive(true);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ShardWave();

        FirstWave();
        FirstWave_Second();

        SecondWaveLeft();
        SecondWaveRight();
        SecondWaveLeft_SecondPhase();

    }
    void FirstEnd()
    {
        enteringNewBoss = true;
    }

    void TriggeringPhase()
    {
        SecondPhase = true;
    }

    void TriggeringPhaseTwo()
    {
        SecondPhaseTwo = true;
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EventManager.GoingToPhase -= TriggeringPhase;
        EventManager.GoingToPhaseTwo -= TriggeringPhaseTwo;
        EventManager.FirstGone -= FirstEnd;
    }
   
    void FirstWave()
    {
        if (Time.time > _spawnSettings[0].NextSpawnTime)
        {
            _spawnSettings[0].NextSpawnTime = Time.time + _spawnSettings[0].SpawnBetween;
            Vector2 SpawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.75f, 1.67f), cameraScreenWrap.y);
            Instantiate(_FirstFall, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

        }
       
    }

    void FirstWave_Second()
    {
        if (SecondPhase == true)
        {
            _FirstFall.SetActive(false);
            if (Time.time > _spawnSettings[1].NextSpawnTime)
            {
                _spawnSettings[1].NextSpawnTime = Time.time + _spawnSettings[1].SpawnBetween;
                Vector2 SpawnPosFirst = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.80f, 1.70f), cameraScreenWrap.y);
                Instantiate(_FirstFelll_secondPhase, SpawnPosFirst, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

    }
 
    //----------------------------------------FIRST ENEMY END-----------------------------------------------------------

    void SecondWaveLeft()
    {
        if (enteringNewBoss == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("second spawn");
            _FirstFelll_secondPhase.SetActive(false);
            if (Time.time > _spawnSettings[2].NextSpawnTime)
            {
                _spawnSettings[2].NextSpawnTime = Time.time + _spawnSettings[2].SpawnBetween;
                Vector2 SpawnPosLeft = new Vector2(cameraScreenWrap.x, Random.Range(4.58f, 2.14f));
                Instantiate(_SecondFallRight, SpawnPosLeft, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            SecondPhase = false;
        }
    }

    void SecondWaveRight()
    {
        if (enteringNewBoss == true)
        {
            if (Time.time > _spawnSettings[3].NextSpawnTime)
            {
                _spawnSettings[3].NextSpawnTime = Time.time + _spawnSettings[3].SpawnBetween;
                Vector2 SpawnPosRight = new Vector2(-cameraScreenWrap.x, Random.Range(4.58f, 2.14f));
                Instantiate(_SecondFallLeft, SpawnPosRight, Quaternion.identity);

            }
        }
    }

    void SecondWaveLeft_SecondPhase()
    {
        if (enteringNewBoss == true)
        {
            if (SecondPhaseTwo == true)
            {
                if (Time.time > _nextSpawnTime_SecondLeft)
                {
                    _nextSpawnTime_SecondLeft = Time.time + SpawnBetween_SecondLeft;
                    Vector2 SpawnPosLeftphrase = new Vector2(cameraScreenWrap.x, Random.Range(4.58f, 2.14f));
                    Instantiate(_SecondFallLeft_Phrase, SpawnPosLeftphrase, Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //----------------------------------------------SECOND ENEMY END---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-----Event Manager Script-----

```
public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action GoingToPhase;
    public static event Action GoingToPhaseTwo;

    public static event Action FirstGone;
    public static event Action SecondGone;

    public static void SecondPhaseTriggered()
    {
        GoingToPhase?.Invoke();
    }
   
    public static void SecondPhaseTriggeredTwo()
    {
        GoingToPhaseTwo?.Invoke();
    }

   public static void PassOn()
    {
        FirstGone?.Invoke();
    }

    public static void PassOnSecond()
    {
        SecondGone?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

----- Boss Script (which tells my spawn manager in a way that this boss has spawn or to go to second phase)----

```
 public class Firstboss : MonoBehaviour
{


    [SerializeField] int healthPoints = 1;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "circle")
        {
            healthPoints--;
            if(healthPoints <= 2)
            {
                EventManager.SecondPhaseTriggered();
            }

            if(healthPoints <= 0)
            {
                EventManager.PassOn();
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---Second boss---- (similar like above but different event input)-----

```
 public class SecondBoss : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int healthPoints = 3;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collisions)
    {
        if (collisions.gameObject.tag == "circle")
        {
            healthPoints--;
            if (healthPoints <= 2)
            {
                EventManager.SecondPhaseTriggeredTwo();
            }

            if (healthPoints <= 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends a bit on your architecture. It could be as simple as a single `nextBossPhase` event. Boss transfors? nextBossPhase please. New Boss spawns? nextBossPhase please. Boss dead? nextBossPhase gimme rewards. Your spawn manager could keep track of how often it got called, would have to have all bosses in correct order, etc. If that does not work, you should add parameters to the event. Which boss name and which phase got called.

Comment: There is some code smell here: You are not naming events after *what happened* but rather after *what is supposed to happen*. The idea of events is that an event just states that something happened (an enemy was killed, a timer ran out, the player reached a destination...). The event receivers then define what happens in that situation (trigger next wave, spawn boss, advance boss to phase two, spawn another boss, load next level...).

Answer (score 0):

The SpawnManager you have here is not very scalable. The more content you add to your game, the longer and messier it is going to get.

A better solution could be to create a separate SpawnManager for each phase. Put them all in your scene, each on a separate game object. Deactivate them all but the first one. When one SpawnManager detects that its phase it over, have it deactivates itself and activate the next one in line.

The best part of this pattern is that you can easily test your game from any point in the phase sequence. Just pick a different SpawnManager to be active in the scene and press the Play button.

You *could* make each of them a separate script, but I would see if I can unify as much as possible so that many phases can be handled by the same script with different values in its variables. And when I still end up with a lot of scripts which share a lot of code, I would probably try to either break it up into multiple components or move the reduntant functionality to an abstract base-class and have all the other SpawnManagers inherit from it.