# How to not create a new event every time I introduce a new "boss"

Tags: unity, c#

I have to create a new event when I'm going to enter a new boss phase when the current boss dies.

This works, but I can see this being messy when I'm going to create a new boss each time. Below is the script I use now:

```
public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action GoingToPhase;
    public static event Action GoingToPhaseTwo;

    public static event Action FirstGone;
    public static event Action SecondGone;

    public static void SecondPhaseTriggered()
    {
        GoingToPhase?.Invoke();
    }
   
    public static void SecondPhaseTriggeredTwo()
    {
        GoingToPhaseTwo?.Invoke();
    }

   public static void PassOn()
    {
        FirstGone?.Invoke();
    }

    public static void PassOnSecond()
    {
        SecondGone?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the same problem as [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/200219/39518), where you got some useful advice about how to avoid this problem. How have you tried putting this advice into practice, and what new help do you need?

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you start putting "One" and "Two" into your variable names, that's a good sign that what you really want is a collection type like an array or a list.

```
public class BossManager : MonoBehaviour {

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct BossPhase {
        public UnityEvent OnPhaseEnter;
        public UnityEvent OnPhaseComplete;
    }

    public List<BossPhase> phases;

    // Start at -1, so calling TryTriggerNextPhase begins at phase [0].
    int _currentPhase = -1;

    public bool TryTriggerPhase(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= phases.Count) return false;       
        phases[index].OnPhaseEnter?.Invoke();
        _currentPhase = index;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryTriggerNextPhase() {
        return TryTriggerPhase(_currentPhase + 1);
    }

    public void CompleteCurrentPhase() {
        phases[_currentPhase].OnPhaseComplete?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This gives you a flexible sequence of phases you can set up in data in the Inspector:

[image: Inspector view]

Or if you prefer, you can also populate the list of phases and their listeners in code. The good thing is that you don't need new functions to trigger each phase - the three here allow you to complete the current phase, trigger the next phase, and jump to an arbitrary phase, no matter how many phases you add.